Issues adding Microsoft 365 account
I'm adding my Microsoft working account to Ubuntu in "Settings-Online Accounts" to access Onedrive directly in File Manager. But it became unavailable after a few hours.



When I click on "Sign in" in pic-3, it shows errors and I can only remove it and add it again.
But the same problem happens again later.

Ubuntu 24.04
Gnome 46

